# Getting error while running command npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, error-handling

npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-14T20_51_39_137Z-debug.log

Comment: Well, it looks self-explanatory: there's no script named "start" in your package.json.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },